# How to replace log(x) by log(abs(x)) automatically in SymPy

Tags: sympy

I am trying to solve differential equation `y'=cot(x)` using Sympy:

```
x = symbols("x")
y = Function("y")(x)
dsolve(diff(y, x) - cot(x))
```

It gives me solution with logarithm: `y(x) = C1 + log(sin(x))`.
How I can replace in this expression log by combination log + abs: `log(sin(x))` -> `log(abs(sin(x)))`? I can do it manually, but it's not very convenient. Is there any way to do it with SymPy tools (something like `subs` command)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `abs` isn't actually needed: the integration constant `C1` can include `I*pi`. The form without `abs` is valid for all complex `x` whereas the `abs` form is only valid for real x.

In any case, you can do it like this:

```
In [6]: sol
Out[6]: y(x) = C₁ + log(sin(x))

In [7]: sol.replace(log, lambda e: log(abs(e)))
Out[7]: y(x) = C₁ + log(│sin(x)│)
```

Comment: Superb! It works as I need. Just I don't want to deal with complex numbers in this project.